# Is there a Database access limit on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a limit to how many database accesses i can add to the db?, for example i have 2 in there right now but is there a cap to the amount?

If i wanted to can i make 100 accesses?

[reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqZY4.jpg)

Comment: Are you asking about number of maximum users or number of maximum concurrent connections?

Comment: not really but is there a maximum connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [mongoDB limits documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) doesn't indicate any limit to the number of accounts/users

Comment: ah okay thanks, I will add a comment to this post if I ever reach the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit number of connections:
mongod  --maxConns = 200